# How to detect new line(or empty line) in a file?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program, which reads text from a file that is specified by the user. Now, this program should detect an empty line.

This is what I have unsuccessfully tried:

```
public static void editFile(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    file = new File(filePath);
    if(file.exists()) {
        fileRead = new FileReader(file);

        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileRead);

        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        while(line != null) {
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            if(line == "") {
                //line = null;
                System.out.println("a");
            }
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

To be more clear:

If I'm passing in a text file with for example this text:

> test1
>      test2
>      
>      test3
>      
>      test4

it should print 2 a's in the console because of the empty spaces, but it doesn't.

Thank you for your time, I am glad for any suggestion you may have.

Comment: What is the exact output? Does it still print the newlines? Have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the comparison is wrong. You can't use `==` to compare two strings, you need to use the `equals` method:

```
if(line.equals(""))
```

Since you are checking for empty string, you can also write

```
if(line.isEmpty())
```

[How do I compare strings in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

BackSlash is entirely correct, and has answered your question. I'd like to add that your code has some errors:

- You're not closing the Reader
- You're not testing the first line for blank
- You're processing the `null` value when reaching EOF

The following corrects these errors.

```
public static void editFile(String filePath) throws IOException
{
    File file = new File(filePath);
    if (file.exists())
    {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        try
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.isEmpty())
                {
                    //line = null;
                    System.out.println("a");
                }
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } finally {
            bufferedReader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
test1
test2
a

test3
a

test4
```

Note: You're still printing the blank line in addition to the "a".

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing wrong is that you're comparing the variable itself, not its value with a null string.
Generally there are built-in functions in the **string** class that return *true* & *false* for checking if it's == with something.

```
if(line.equals("")) { ... }
```

Or you can just use any alternative way.